# How to add extra option in dynamic Drop down List at the end of the list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to add extra option name as `Other` at the end of dynamic drop down list using MVC C#. When drop down is loaded with data there always be an extra option with `Other` at the end of drop down list.

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetSubjects() {
    try {
        var subjectList = HelperMethods.ListofEntity<Subject>().Select(t => new SelectListItem {
            Text = t.SubjectName,
            Value = Convert.ToString(t.ID)
        }).ToList();
        return subjectList;
    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
          throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: The just add it - `subjectList.Add(new SelectListItem(){ Value = .... });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`List<T>.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
subjectList.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "Your Text",
    Value = YourValue
});
```